# snap scrolling Angular without direct children

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a HTML structure like

```
body
    app-root
        ng-component
            header-bar
            router-outlet
            ng-component
                section 1
                section 2
                section 3
                section 4
```

everything is in flex and I'm happy of the result.

But Now I need to implement snap-scrolling to achieve something similar to:
https://www.clearstep.health/

The scroll is the body one and works well but actually the scroll-snap-align: start is not working on the section.

I tried to define overflow:hidden on the body and add an overflow-y:scroll to the ng-component but this is not working at all.

Is there an easy js/Angular library to do it. I need a fast way.

Typically I would like to stuck the user on section 2 and when he scrolls down to change the content of section 2 (like a carousel). When he finished the carousel he can scroll down "normally".